# Cannot get the context of activity extends CountDownTimer

Tags: java, android, countdowntimer

I would like to transfer a variable from this activity to another one, but I find it impossible to get the context of the activity.

I have tried every single option and I have been searching arching through StackOverflow and it looks people use getContextApplication() but it doesn't work for me.

Any ideas?

```
public class CountDownCalculator2 extends CountDownTimer {

    private String countDown;

    public CountDownCalculator2(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
      super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

        long day = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(millisUntilFinished);
        millisUntilFinished -= TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(day);

        long hour = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millisUntilFinished);
        millisUntilFinished -= TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(hour);

        long minute = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished);
        millisUntilFinished -= TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(minute);

        long second = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished);

        this.countDown = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d:%02d", day, hour, minute, second);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, VocabularyAdapter.class);
        intent.putExtra("timer", countDown);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() { 
        countDown = "In Cinemas";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To use activity context, you need to pass it

```
private Context context;

public CountDownCalculator2(Context context, long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
    super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
    this.context = context;
}
```